# JPA: How is the lifecycle of EntityListener class?

Tags: java, jpa

Thinking about how to program time measuring between`@PrePersist` and `@PostPersist`, I came to the question:

When I'm using `@PrePersist` for taking the time and store it in a global variable, e.g. `long timeStart` and then calculating the time difference in `@PostPersist` by accessing `timeStart` it works.

Now my question:
Does it works because my `EntityListener` class is a Singleton object (and all Callbacks are made on only one instance) ?
Or even does the `EntityListener` class is somekind stateful ?

Comment: I think, your `EntityListener` want to keep some value for all instance of  `EntityListener` class? do you also use spring?

Comment: `EntityListener` is provided in JPA. I'm using no web framework (but could).